# Search top 1000 emails by subject containing a string using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft Graph call that works:

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(subject) eq 'sample'
```

I actually want is for Microsoft Graph to search the Top 1000 emails and return those with a `subject` that contain `'sample'`.

I realize that `contains` is not implemented in Graph yet, but does anyone have any workarounds for this?

The only solution I can think of is to retrieve all email IDs and subjects use a JSON parser to search and filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the search operator, i.e:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:sample"
```

I think this should work, the search uses Keyword Query Language to formulate valid search queries.

More information can be found here: [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference).

Comment: Cheers I suppose that does a fuzzy match on the subject, is that right? The only issue is that I cannot seem to apply it to only unread emails, I was trying 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(isRead) eq false&$search="subject:sample"

Comment: It seems the Graph API is quite restrictive as of yet, the only solution I can think of is to include the filter in the search string:                       ?$search="subject:sample AND isRead = false"

Comment: I tried $search and $search which is also not allowed -  I will see if i can add 2 properties in $search. Thanks

Comment: Also yes I believe its a fuzzy search

Comment: This is absolutely spot on but it is worth noting the results are limited to 250 messages.